# JSON Data formatting incorrectly in Python Requests JSON API POST statement

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am trying to post a set of json data to a server. I seem to be missing something because I am getting errors that include the following: (Note:CPAPI is the name of the API)

> "SerializationException - could not deserialize "application/json'
>   request using CPAPI.ServiceModule.AddCustomerRequest" \nError:
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException:Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type > > 
>   'AddCustomerRequest' got string starting with:
>   \"{\\"SY_WRKGRP\\":{\\"WRKGRP_ID\\":\\"7\\"},\\"AR_CUST\\":\r\n

Here is my code:

```
import requests, json

url = "https://shipping:52000/customer/"

payload1 = '{"SY_WRKGRP":{"WRKGRP_ID":"7"},"AR_CUST": {"CUST_NO":"6377123456","NAM":"Rob O","NAM_UPR":"ROBO","FST_NAM":"Rob","FST_NAM_UPR":"ROB","LST_NAM":"O"}}'

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "XXXX",
    "APIKey": "YYYY",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

r = requests.post(url, json=payload1, headers=headers,verify=False)

print()
print(r)
print(r.text)
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The value passed to `requests.post()`'s `json` keyword is supposed to be an unserialized Python value (e.g., a `dict`), not a serialized JSON string.  Either drop the single quotes around `payload1` to turn it into a `dict` or use `data=payload1` instead of `json=payload1`.

Comment: Very much appreciated.  I am still having issues with the API, but you opened my eyes to something that I didn't completely understand, that inevitably will help me.